# Scanner in while loop stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java

I have the following code which seems to be getting stuck in the while loop but I cannot figure out why. Commenting out the while loop allows the code to run cleanly.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] pArgs)throws FileNotFoundException {
        Main mainObject = new Main();
        mainObject.run();
    }

    private void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        readInputFile();

    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> readInputFile(){
        //reads input file and creates array of integers

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try {
            File in = new File("p01-in.txt");

            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                System.out.println("Tada!");
                int tempInt = scanner.nextInt();
                integerList.add(tempInt);
                return integerList;

            }

        }

        catch(Exception ioException){
            System.out.println("Oops, could not open 'p01-in.txt' for reading. The program is ending.");
            System.exit(-100);
        }

        finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
        return integerList;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding print statements in several places to narrow down where the error is. The code executes down to the while loop and then gets stuck and must be manually stopped. However, what throws me off a bit is that I've added a print statement to the top of the while loop and I get nothing. So it isn't actually executing any of the code in the while loop itself but that's where it's stuck?

Input file

```
2 8 3
2 9
8
6
3 4 6 1 9
```

Comment: It can't be stuck if you have a return statement in the loop

Comment: When you run your code in a debugger and break it, where does it end up?

Comment: @JosephSible It doesn't break. It just continues to run.

Comment: In any case a link to the input file wouldn't harm, or an input sample that reproduces the behavior. Then we can move from guessing and theory building to experiments ;)

Comment: I said when you break it with the debugger. It can't keep running once you break it with the debugger.

Comment: @JosephSible Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. I'm brand new to Java.
Sorry I thought I had linked the input file. One second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You're completely ignoring the file you're opening, and reading from stdin instead. It's not actually infinitely looping; it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't reading a file; it's waiting for you to *type something*.

If you want to read a File, you need to pass the file to the Scanner , not `System.in`.

However, using Scanners is generally the wrong pattern for file reading compared to using a BufferedReader or, preferably, Streams

```
List<Integer> integerList  = new ArrayList<>();

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("in.txt"))) {
    stream.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .forEach(integerList::add);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(integerList);
```